# Can you speed up "for " loop in python with sorting ?

Tags: python, list

If I have a long unsorted list of 300k elements, will sorting this list first and then do a "for" loop on list speed up code? I need to do a "for loop" regardless, cant use list comprehension.

```
sortedL=[list].sort() 

for i in sortedL:
  (if i is somenumber)
     "do some work"
```

How could I signal to python that sortedL is sorted and not read whole list. Is there any benefit to sorting a list? If there is then how can I implement?

Comment: No, it won't speed up the for loop.  However, it can speed up your search, assuming you know the "somenumber" that you need to  "do some work" for.

Comment: If you are trying to find only one number `somenumber` in a `list`, you should do `somenumber in list`. No need to sort the array

Comment: Note that `[list].sort()` doesn't do what you think. First, `foo.sort()` sorts `foo` in-place and returns `None`; you want `sorted(foo)`. Second, `[list]` is a list with one element, the type `list`. Assuming you have a list `foo`, you probably want to sort `foo` rather than `[foo]`, because the latter (having only one element) will be unchanged after sorting. (And if `list` is actually the name of your variable, don't do that; never give a variable the same name as a built-in type, function, etc.)

Comment: It depends on just how many lookups you're doing, but if your list has no duplicates, you're most likely better off using a `set` (or a `dict`, if your list is more complex than just the numbers): You can find any value in one step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear that you're considering sorting the list so that you could then quickly look for `somenumber`.

Whether the sorting will be worth it depends on whether you are going to search once, or repeatedly:

- If you're only searching once, sorting the list will not speed things up. Just iterate over the list looking for the element, and you're done.
- If, on the other hand, you need to search for values repeatedly, by all means pre-sort the list. This will enable you to use [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to quickly look up values.

The third option is to store elements in a `dict`. This might offer the fastest lookups, but will probably be less memory-efficient than using a list.

Comment: Why a `dict`? They're not being mapped to anything. Maybe you meant a `set`?

Comment: I just want to add for future people. You can use the elements in the list as keys and True as values. It doesn't matter if they are not distinct because we simply want to know if an element is in the list.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search within a sorted `list`, you need an algorithm that takes advantage of the sorting.

One possibility is the built-in [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module. This is a bit of a pain to use, but there's a recipe in the documentation for building simple sorted-list functions on top of it.

With that recipe, you can just write this:

```
i = index(sortedL, somenumber)
```

Of course if you're just sorting for the purposes of speeding up a single search, this is a bit silly. Sorting will take O(N log N) time, then searching will take O(log N), for a total time of O(N log N); just doing a linear search will take O(N) time. So, unless you're typically doing log N searches on the same list, this isn't worth doing.

If you don't actually need sorting, just fast lookups, you can use a `set` instead of a `list`. This gives you O(1) lookup for all but pathological cases.

Also, if you want to *keep* a list sorted while continuing to add/remove/etc., consider using something like [`blist.sortedlist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) instead of a plain list.

Answer (score 3):

The cost of a `for` loop in python is **not** dependent on whether the input data is sorted.

That being said, you might be able to `break` out of the `for` loop early or have other computation saving things at the algorithm level if you sort first.